# String formatting in python 3 without print function

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to understand how `"%s%s" %(a,a)` is working in below code I have only seen it inside print function thus far.Could anyone please explain how it is working inside int()?

```
a=input()
b=int("%s%s" %(a,a))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this `"%s"` format has been borrowed from C `printf` format, but is much more interesting because it doesn't *belong* to `print` statement. Note that it involves just one argument passed to `print` (or to any function BTW):

```
print("%s%s" % (a,a))
```

and not (like C) a variable number of arguments passed to some functions that accept & understand them:

```
printf("%s%s,a,a);
```

It's a standalone way of creating a string from a string template & its arguments (which for instance solves the tedious issue of: "I want a logger with formatting capabilities" which can be achieved with great effort in C or C++, using variable arguments + `vsprintf` or C++11 variadic recursive templates).

Note that this format style is now considered legacy. Now you'd better use `format`, where the placeholders are wrapped in `{}`.

One of the direct advantages here is that since the argument is repeated you just have to do:

```
int("{0}{0}".format(a))
```

(it references twice the sole argument in position 0)

Both legacy and `format` syntaxes are detailed with examples on https://pyformat.info/

or since python 3.6 you can use *fstrings*:

```
>>> a = 12
>>> int(f"{a}{a}")
1212
```

Comment: Thanks ! Can I use fstrings in print function as well ? Like `print (f"{a}{a}")`  I tried it , it gave me syntax error.

Comment: it works but from 3.6. Below version 3.6 use `format` instead of %

Answer (score 2):

`%` is in a way just syntactic sugar for a function that accepts a string and a `*args` (a format and the parameters for formatting) and returns a string which is the format string with the embedded parameters. So, you can use it any place that a `string` is acceptable.

BTW, `%` is a bit obsolete, and "{}{}".format(a,a) is the more 'modern' approach here, and is more obviously a string method that returns another string.